# flutter, RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4de33 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT

Tags: flutter

I use `tabBar`,

I want to change `appBar` title when a tab is selected, but I get a error.

code that I get error.

```
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear, color: Colors.black),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
      title: TabBarView(
        children: [Text("Album"), Text("사진"), Text("동영상")],
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(
      tabs: [
        Tab(text: "앨범"),
        Tab(text: "사진"),
        Tab(text: "동영상"),
      ],
      labelColor: Colors.black,
      indicatorColor: Colors.black,
      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black26,
    ),
  ),
```

If I get rid of `appBar` `title`, I don't get error.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can add `TabController` and add a `listener` so that whenever you are switching the Tab, the `setState()` kicks in and the `appBar` title change.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _controller;
  final List<Tab> _tab = [new Tab(text: "First",), Tab(text: "Second",), Tab(text: "Third",)];
  var _currentTab;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _controller = new TabController(length: _tab.length, vsync: this);
    _currentTab = _tab[0];
    _controller.addListener(_selectedTab);
  }

  void _selectedTab() {
    setState(() {
      _currentTab = _tab[_controller.index];
    });
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text(_currentTab.text),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: TabBar(controller: _controller,tabs: _tab),
    );
  }
}
```